# Converting an XML to CSV with XSL - how to retrieve value for tag in foreach

Tags: java, xml, xslt

I'm trying to convert an XML file a CSV file and i'm stucked in some point.

This is a sample version of my XML

```
<xc:XmlCache xc:action="Update" xmlns:mp="mx.MarketParameters" xmlns:xc="XmlCache" xmlns:sc="mx.MarketParameters.Securities" xmlns:scpr="mx.MarketParameters.Securities.Prices">
    <xc:XmlCacheArea xc:value="MarketParameters">
        <mp:nickName xc:value="GLBORF" xc:subset="Reference">
            <mp:date xc:value="TODAY">
                <sc:security>
                    <scpr:price>
                        <scpr:type xc:value="Index">
                            <scpr:market xc:value="FB">
                                <scpr:label xc:value="SEB IMMOINVEST">
                                    <scpr:maturity xc:value="SPOT" xc:type="Fields">
                                        <mp:lst xc:type="Field" xc:keyFormat="N">23.14</mp:lst>
                                        <mp:quotation xc:type="Field">PRICE</mp:quotation>
                                        <mp:ask1 xc:type="Field" xc:keyFormat="N">23.14</mp:ask1>
                                        <mp:max xc:type="Field" xc:keyFormat="N">23.14</mp:max>
                                        <mp:clo xc:type="Field" xc:keyFormat="N">23.14</mp:clo>
                                        <mp:min xc:type="Field" xc:keyFormat="N">23.14</mp:min>
                                        <mp:bid1 xc:type="Field" xc:keyFormat="N">23.14</mp:bid1>
                                    </scpr:maturity>
                                </scpr:label>
                            </scpr:market>
                        </scpr:type>
                    </scpr:price>
                </sc:security>
            </mp:date>
        </mp:nickName>
    </xc:XmlCacheArea>
</xc:XmlCache>
```

This is my XSL:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format ">
    <xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        XmlCacheArea,nickName,date,type,market,label,maturity, lst,quotation,ask1, max,clo,min,bid1
        <xsl:for-each select="//XmlCacheArea">
            <xsl:for-each select="//nickName">
                <xsl:for-each select="//date">
                    <xsl:for-each select="//type">
                        <xsl:for-each select="//market">
                            <xsl:for-each select="//label">
                                <xsl:for-each select="//maturity">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="concat(XmlCacheArea,',',nickName,',',date,',',type,',',market,',',label,',',maturity,',', lst,',',quotation,',',ask1,',', max,',',clo,',',min,',',bid1,'&#xA;')"/>
                                </xsl:for-each>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is the output I am obtaining:

> ```
>     XmlCacheArea  nickName    date    type    market  label   maturity     lst    quotation   ask1     max    clo min bid1
>                               23.14   PRICE   23.14   23.14   23.14   23.14   23.14
> ```

And this is the one i want to obtain:

> ```
>     XmlCacheArea  nickName    date    type    market  label   maturity     lst    quotation   ask1     max    clo min bid1
>     MarketParameters  GLBORF  TODAY   Index   FB  SEB IMMOINVEST  SPOT    23.14   PRICE   23.14   23.14   23.14   23.14   23.14
> ```

I am unable to retreive the value from the tags in the foreach loop.

Can someone please help me?

Kind Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Nested `xsl:for-each` is not needed.
- `//x` in `xsl:for-each` is not suitable because it selects whole descendant `x` elements from document-node.
- You should use `namespace` for specifying elements.

Here is my example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:sc="mx.MarketParameters.Securities"
    xmlns:xc="XmlCache"
    xmlns:mp="mx.MarketParameters"
    xmlns:scpr="mx.MarketParameters.Securities.Prices">

    <xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:text>XmlCacheArea,nickName,date,type,market,label,maturity, lst,quotation,ask1, max,clo,min,bid1&#xA;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:for-each select="//xc:XmlCacheArea/mp:nickName/mp:date/sc:security/scpr:price/scpr:type/scpr:market/scpr:label/scpr:maturity">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(ancestor::xc:XmlCacheArea/@xc:value,',',ancestor::mp:nickName/@xc:value,',',ancestor::mp:date/@xc:value,',',ancestor::scpr:type/@xc:value,',',ancestor::scpr:market/@xc:value,',',ancestor::scpr:label/@xc:value,',',@xc:value,',', mp:lst,',',mp:quotation,',',mp:ask1,',', mp:max,',',mp:clo,',',mp:min,',',mp:bid1,'&#xA;')"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And the result:

[image: Result CSV opend via Excel]

Comment: thanks! I managed to do that using ../../ and so on instead of ancestor.

Your solution clearly improves mine